# Show comment in history.phtml

Tags: magento2, php

I need to show order comment in file

> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order/history.phtml

I tried to use the code:

```
<?php $_history = $_order->getVisibleStatusHistory() ?>
<?php if (count($_history)): ?>
<div class="order-additional order-comments">
<dl class="order-about">
<?php foreach ($_history as $_historyItem): ?>
<dd>
<span class='lowcase'><?php echo $_historyItem->getComment()?></span>
</dd>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</dl>
</div>
<?php endif?>
```

Did not work.

Comment: could you please add `$_order` object code ?

Answer (score 0):

First try with this code of Object Manager, if you get value converts it into Dependency Injection. Code are:

```
$orderId = $orderId;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
$order->addStatusHistoryComment('This comment is programatically added to last order in this Magento setup');
$order->save();
```

Hope this will help You !!